# fulltext query in joomla

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, joomla3.1

How do I buld a fulltext search query with joomla objects. I have been trying but it's not working

```
   $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__unis_subjects AS s');
        $query->join('', '#__unis AS u ON s.university = u.id');
        $query->join('', '#__unis_faculties AS f ON f.id = s.faculty');
        $query->where('MATCH (s.subject) AGAINST ("' . $query . '")');

        if (!$db->query()) {
            throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
        }

        $data = $db->loadObjectList();

        var_dump($query);
```

the result outputs template config parameters

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? You could help out a lot of others by posting your solution here - you're one of the top results for this search...

Answer (score 1):

Your table must be set up using ENGINE = MyISAM (not InnoDB) and the columns you're searching must be set to FULLTEXT indexing.

You can easily set your table to MyISAM in phpMyAdmin via the 'SQL' tab...

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

In Joomla 2.5+ (likely 3+ as well) in my query as a where clause I used...

```
->where('MATCH ('.$db->quoteName('columnname').') AGAINST ('.$db->quote($words_or_phrase_to_search_for).')');
```

Further testing is in order but so far it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Of course for $db - It's set up as $db = JFactory::getDbo();
All Regular Joomla select query standards were used... $query = $db->getQuery(true); and then $query->select(array('*'))->from('#__some_table')->[insert my where clause above here]

Comment: You can also use multiple column names to search through in the MATCH portion if you so choose (perhaps you want to search through both the title and description for example) but you'll have to set it up using a , to separate each column name. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

The $query inside the where condition seems strange to me.

Comment: It's a FULLTEXT search, and to my limited knowledge the table must be set to ENGINE = MyISAM (not InnoDB) and the column(s) you'll be performing the search on must also be set to accept FULLTEXT searches. This is what I have so far...
->where('MATCH ('.$db->quote('name').') AGAINST ('.$db->quote($title).')'); I get nothing back, so I'm doing something wrong myself (perhaps I missed something in the table setup). Glasnhost, you should probably have added a comment instead of an actual answer with a response like the one you gave.