# SQL fulltext search - Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysqli, joomla

I´m trying to do a fulltext search in a Joomla system with this query:

```
SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`article_id`,`body`,`created_time`
FROM `#__user_notes`
WHERE (`user_id` = '660' AND `article_id` IN (23, 24) AND `id` < '385') 
OR (MATCH (body) AGAINST (`test`) AND `id` < '385' AND `user_id` = '660')
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

This error is thrown:

```
JDatabaseExceptionExecuting: Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'
```

Works fine without the fulltext search line:

```
OR (MATCH (body) AGAINST (`test`) AND `id` < '385' AND `user_id` = '660')
```

I´ve set the `ENGINE` to `MYISAM` as this answer suggest [fulltext query in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933830/fulltext-query-in-joomla)

Comment: You already have a Joomla Stack Exchange account, please post your Joomla questions there for the benefit of that community.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don’t see this as a Joomla question. But I wanted to mention it, in case that it had something to do with the error. I would also use the Joomla Stack Exchange for question clearly related to Joomla :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Unknown column in where clause error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480327/mysql-unknown-column-in-where-clause-error)  (super-exact duplicate... right down to the `test` text value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove backtick from your query.

```
OR (MATCH (body) AGAINST (`test`) AND `id` < '385' AND `user_id` = '660')
```

above should be replaced with

```
OR (MATCH (body) AGAINST ('test') AND `id` < '385' AND `user_id` = '660')
```

Mysql uses backtick for column name but `test` here is a text that you want to search.

Because you are using Joomla so in Joomla, instead of using `$db->quoteName` you should use `$db->quote`. `quoteName` is used to escape column name and `quote` is used for values